# Does .wiki TLD Domain supports adsense?

Tags: adsense, google-search-console

I plan to start new website with .wiki tld domain extension. is it supports adsense. please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TLD is not mentioned in the google tos. So, yes it's allowed as long as you do not break any other of the google rules: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en